# weird issue - cssSelector unable to find objects using css structure

Tags: css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

I am facing a weird issue when locating elements using `cssSelector` with webdriver.

On a fresh environment that I setup on Windows, cssSelector is unable to find objects when the identification is done using the structure of the CSS – for example `findElement(By.cssSelector(elementId > div(1) > span(1)))`.

Identification works fine if done by id only - `findElement(By.cssSelector(elementId))`.

We are using `WebDriverWait` everywhere, so it’s not a timing issue. In fact, it’s not even waiting for the specified interval. It quits within milliseconds with error similar to the stack trace given at the bottom.

The same code runs fine on all fresh Linux environments and my old Windows environment. I have followed the same environment setup steps everywhere.

1. Get Eclipse Java EE Helios SR2
2. Install Maven from the ‘Help > Install New Software’ option – http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e
3. Setup TestNG from the ‘Help > Install New Software’ option – http://beust.com/eclipse
4. Set the -vm argument in eclipse.ini
5. Import my project into eclipse – thus the same maven version, TestNG version etc. gets specified everywhere.

Any idea why this is happening on all Windows environments that I am setting up now?

STACK TRACE SAMPLE

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to find element with
>   css selector == #GraphicalPane > div:nth-of-type(1) >
>   div:nth-of-type(1) > img (WARNING: The server did not provide any
>   stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 344 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.19.0', revision: '15848', time: '2012-02-08
>   16:25:03' System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86',
>   os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_25' Driver info:
>   driver.version: RemoteWebDriver   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:170)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:123)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:439)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:226)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:291)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:406)    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:218)
>     at my.domain.product.webconsole.Hardware$10.apply(Hardware.java:589)
>     at my.domain.product.webconsole.Hardware$10.apply(Hardware.java:1)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:201)
>     at
>   my.domain.product.webconsole.Hardware.findobject1(Hardware.java:587)
>     at
>   my.domain.product.testsuite.testcase1(HardwareApplianceRack.java:48)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1197)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1122)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1030)   at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)     at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)  at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
(elementId > div(1) > span(1))
```

try using

```
elementId>div:first-child>span:first-child
```

Have you checked e.g. in firepath whether you element has been located properly?

Comment: Hi Eugene,

Thanks for the answer.

I'm sorry I should have given more detail in the description. 'div(1)' in my code translates to '>div:nth-of-type(1)'. You can see in the second line of the stack trace that the actual identifier is - "#GraphicalPane > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(1) > img".

Yes, I had confirmed in the IE developer toolbar that the object is present.